# Cordova WhiteList does not allow access to my Server

Tags: php, cordova, cordova-plugins, whitelist

I can not connect with my database because my URL is rejected. The url i want to access is this:

> http://192.168.0.16/checkUser.php?nombre=asi&clave=1234

I have some urls with same structure, and i have tried this in my config.xml file but did not worked.

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://192.168.0.16" subdomains="true" />
```

or

> ```
> <access origin="http://192.168.0.16/*"/>
> ```

This is the complete code where i create the path and call the functions to connect to my database:

```
function pullUser(userName,apodo,secondName,lastName,pass1,userMail){
    var method='GET';
    var url = appConstants.requestpullUserURL();
    //alert('cogidaUrl: '+ url);
    var path = url + "?nombre="+userName+"&apodo="+apodo+"&apellido1="+secondName+
    "&apellido2="+lastName+"&email="+userMail+"&clave="+pass1;
    console.log(path);
    //alert('El path es: '+ path);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        //alert('onready. readyState:'+xhr.readyState+' status: '+xhr.status);
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            resp = xhr.responseText;
            //alert('Registro completado');
            transitionLog();
            }else{
                //alert('devuelve false');
                return false; 
            }
    }
    xhr.open(method, path, true); //Creamos la peticion
    resp = xhr.send(); // FALLA AQUI SIN SERVER
    alert('despues del send');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what are some of the errors you're getting?

Comment: URL blocked by whitelist: http://192.168.0.16/checkUser.php?apodo=k&clave=k

Comment: I solved it, the problem was that whitelist plugin was not added. I do not know why... I solved with this bash code over my app directory: cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, adding the whitelist pluggin. I don´t know why when i created the project did not added itself. This bash code on my app directory solved it: cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git